# How can I programmatically access fields in an i18n translation file? (using r18n and Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, internationalization, sinatra

I am developing a `Sinatra` based web-app using the `Sinatra r18n` internationalisation system.

My `./i18n/en.yml` `r18n` translation file contains the following:

```
season:
  summer:  !!pl
    0: no Summers
    1: one Summer
    n: "%1 Summers"
  autumn: !!pl
    0: no Autumns
    1: one Autumn
    n: "%1 Autumns"
  winter: !!pl
    0: no Winters
    1: one Winter
    n: "%1 Winters"
  spring: !!pl
    0: no Springs
    1: one Spring
    n: "%1 Springs"
```

In my code I can easily access `"Total: #{t.season.summer season_count}."` but I'm having trouble trying to access my season names programatically.

`s = t.season[season_name]` returns a [`Translation`](https://github.com/ai/r18n/blob/master/r18n-core/lib/r18n-core/translation.rb) object.

I've looked at [the source for a `Translation`](https://github.com/ai/r18n/blob/master/r18n-core/lib/r18n-core/translation.rb) however and can't see the obvious way I'd generate my translated text from that `Translation` and a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get Translation, because you don’t send count to season[season_name], so R18n return subhash. Just use:

```
s = t.season[season_name, season_count]
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's just taught me something.